# Add adblock in webview

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview, adblock

I'm trying to add adblock in my fragment, and when I'm tryed inisialize webview I got underline `this` on `new AdBlockerWebView.init(this).initializeWebView(webView);` line

```
package com.example.bottomnavigationview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.monstertechno.adblocker.AdBlockerWebView;
import com.monstertechno.adblocker.util.AdBlocker;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
        WebView webView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        new AdBlockerWebView.init(this).initializeWebView(webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Browser_home());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://cyber.sports.ru/dota2/match/");
        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                        if(webView != null){
                            if (webView.canGoBack()){
                                webView.goBack();
                            } else {
                                getActivity().onBackPressed();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

where I need put line new `AdBlockerWebView.init(this).initializeWebView(webView);` to fix my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what param takes `init(...)` method? I bet its `Context`, so you can use `this` in `Activity`, `Service` and other classes extending `Context`. but `Fragment` isn't extending `Context`, don't have own, is using parent `Activity`s context, so in there you may use e.g. `requireContext()` or `webView.getContext()` as param for `init` method

```
new AdBlockerWebView.init(webView.getContext()).initializeWebView(webView);
```

assuming you are using [THIS](https://github.com/MonsterTechnoGits/WebViewAdblock-Library/blob/master/adblocker/src/main/java/com/monstertechno/adblocker/AdBlockerWebView.java) library